# Filtering through an object - but add class

Tags: javascript, class, filter

I have a filter, however I would like to add a class rather than hide them.

Is this possible?  I am using jquery so can use addClass() or toggleClass()

```
filteredMetrics: function () {  
    var self = this;
    return this.metrics.filter(function (metrics) {
        return metrics.type_name == self.active_market;
    }).slice(0, 5);
},
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: be more specific about the code.

Comment: The issue is it filters the div rather than adds a class to the filtered or unfiltered divs.

Comment: @LeBlaireau Then why are you using filter? Are you looking for something like `forEach`, check some condition, apply class? What should be the output expected?

Comment: What do you want to add the class to? It looks like `this.metrics` is an array of Javascript objects, not DOM elements.